# Drawing ellipse in silverlight - incorrect placement

Tags: c#, silverlight, drawing, shapes

I've got this function that just draws an ellipse and places it on the given grid

```
    public void drawEllipse(double top, double left, double height, double width, Grid grid)
    {
        Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();
        ellipse.Height = height;
        ellipse.Width = width;
        SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush();
        brush.Color = Colors.Black;
        ellipse.Stroke = brush;
        ellipse.Fill = brush;
        Canvas.SetTop(ellipse, top);
        Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, left);
        grid.Children.Add(ellipse);
    }
```

However, for some reason, it only wants to place the ellipse in the center of the grid, or (given fourth quadrant arguments) the fourth quadrant of the grid.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding your ellipse to a `Grid` control, but you're setting the `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left` properties. Without the ellipse actually being on a `Canvas`, those two properties don't do anything. Either add a `Canvas` and use `Canvas.Children.Add` instead of `Grid.Children.Add`, or change your `Canvas.SetTop` and `Canvas.SetLeft` calls with calls to `Grid.SetRow` and `Grid.SetColumn`.

Comment: Ahh, I create lines in a similar fashion and I use `Canvas.SetZIndex`, which works even though I add the lines to a grid.

Comment: `SetZIndex` is actually on `Panel`, a superclass of `Canvas`. When you code `Canvas.SetZIndex`, you're actually calling `Panel.SetZIndex`.

Comment: Oh! Well I just changed the grid to a canvas and it works now, thanks!